# Using float in OOP method overloading gives error

Tags: c#, oop

If I do,

```
public class test
{
    public int add(int a, float b)
    {
        return a + Convert.ToInt32(b);
    }

    public int add(float a, int b)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(a) + b;
    }
}
```

Then it compiles successfully but gives late binding runtime error:

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties
```

But If I do

```
public class test
{
    public int add(int a, float b)
    {
        return a + Convert.ToInt32(b);
    }

    public int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(a) + b;
    }
}
```

Then it works properly and calls second add method in case of test.add(1,2). It also works in case when I replace float with decimal.

Can I have little explanation on above error?

Comment: Show how you call methods.

Comment: Please can you show your calling code for the erroring example, including all variable declarations.

Comment: @Hamlet, I am calling methods with obj.add(1,2); as show in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because an int is implicitly convertable to a float so the compiler doesn't know whether to choose to convert the first parameter to float or the second parameter to float. They are both equally worthy conversions.

At your call site, disabmiguate by calling with a float and an int, not two ints:

```
test t  = new test();
t.add(1.0f, 2);
t.add(1, 2.0f);
```

Comment: Yes, got it now. We need to pass variable to match desired datatype to make it working. There is also one more case, If I already have one more method with add(int, int) then It will not give error and works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are passing two integer numbers or two floats into your *add* method. In first case compiler can convert either first argument to float, or second argument. Thus you have two methods possible to call. In second case in simply calls *add* with two integers.

Take a look at [Better function member definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691338%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Function member will be better, if

> **for each argument**, the implicit conversion from *AX* to *PX* is not worse
>   than the implicit conversion from *AX* to *QX*, and

But that's not true *for each argument* of your methods. Because if you are passing integer arguments, only first argument is not worse. Second argument is worse. (vise versa for floats)

Answer (score 1):

`int` is implicitly convertible to `float`, so in first example compiler has two equivalent options and just can't decide from call `add(1,2)` which overload to use, because there is no hints for him.

In second case there is no need for conversion, and the compiler picks the most suited overload.

If you add another method to second scenario, like this:

```
public float add(float  a, float b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

and call it with explicit type of parameter, like `add(1f, 3);` - it will get called

Not digging into details, compiler always tries to pick most suitable overload and tries to do as less convention, as possible. If it stuck with ambiguity - it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

i have try your coding parts in our itself. No error faced.

```
class Program
{

        public int add(int a, float b)
        {
            return a + Convert.ToInt32(b);
        }

        public int add(float a, int b)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(a) + b;
        }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Program pr = new Program();
       int k= pr.add(12, 203.9f);
       int kk = pr.add(203.9f, 12);
       Console.WriteLine(k);
       Console.WriteLine(kk);
    }
}
```

just check out this coding.